# background changing carousel help for my local carousel in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to make the second Carousel (with solutions and all and with changing background color) in Twitter Bootstrap as shown in :-http://solutions.mckinsey.com/index/

I am not sure that how the background changing part is being handled. Could you guys help me in it.

This is what I did with my current Carousel:-

```
<div class="personalized-carousel-module media-module">


            <div id="myCarouselforthis" class="carousel slide">
              <div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner-at-home">


                <div class="item active" id="home-carousel-inner">
                  <a href="/myfirstlink/index.html">
                        <div class="some-class"></div>
                        <span>Title</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div class="item">
                      <a href="/myfirstlink2/index.html">
                        <div class="some-class2"></div>
                        <span>Title2</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="media/sample-image.jpg" alt="">

                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="arrow arrow-left hidden-phone" href="#myCarouselforthis" data-slide="prev"></a>
              <a class="arrow arrow-right hidden-phone" href="#myCarouselforthis" data-slide="next"></a>
            </div>



        </div>
```

### EDIT

While looking at the code, I realised, that it's being done through `<div class="solution-preview" value="primary-two-background">`. Can I anyone explain, how the `value` element of div makes it change the colors?

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-two-background">
                <a href="/Index/solutions/periscope/">
                    <h2>Periscope</h2>
                </a>
                <p>
Improves return on sales through better pricing, promotions, assortment, and performance management </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-five-background">
                <a href="/Index/solutions/objective-health/">
                    <h2>Objective Health</h2>
                </a>
                <p>
Supports community hospitals and small regional systems to improve their cost performance and strategy </p>
            </div>
        </li>
```

### Work Done uptill now

So, by using CSS and JS from the same site for the learning purposes, I did the following:-

```
<div class="module colored home-solutions primary-two-background">


            <div id="myCarouselforsolutions" class="carousel slide">
              <div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner-at-home">


                   <div class="content-container">

                        <h1 id="num-solutions"></h1>
                        <h2>SOLUTIONS</h2>
                        <div id="swipe-container-home-solutions">

                            <div class="item active" id="solutions-slide-dimensions">

                                <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-two-background">
                                    <a href="/Index/solutions/periscope/">
                                        <h2>Periscope</h2>
                                    </a>
                                    <p>
                                        Improves return on sales through better pricing, promotions, assortment, and performance management </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                             <div class="item" id="solutions-slide-dimensions">

                                <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-five-background">
                                    <a href="/Index/solutions/objective-health/">
                                        <h2>Objective Health</h2>
                                    </a>
                                    <p> Supports community hospitals and small regional systems to improve their cost performance and strategy</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>



                        </div>

                  </div>



              </div>
              <a class="arrow arrow-left hidden-phone" href="#myCarouselforsolutions" data-slide="prev"></a>
              <a class="arrow arrow-right hidden-phone" href="#myCarouselforsolutions" data-slide="next"></a>
            </div>



        </div>
```

The problem is that it does look fine layout wise, but the slider for the carousel is not working ... and I am unable to figure out.

### SOLUTION

Did it something like this:-

So I did it something like this:-

```
$('#myCarouselforsolutions').carousel({
          interval: 3000
        });

        var slideFrom;
        var slideTo;
        $('#myCarouselforsolutions').on('slide',function(e){
            slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
            slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();


            if (typeof slideTo == "undefined") {
                slideTo = 2;
            }
            //console.log ("slide To " + slideTo + " and From " + slideFrom);
            $('.media-module').removeClass('primary-one-background')
                                .removeClass('primary-two-background')
                                .removeClass('primary-three-background')
                                .removeClass('primary-four-background')
                                .removeClass('primary-five-background')
                                .addClass($(solution_list[slideTo]).attr('value'));
            });



            $("#prev-solution, #next-solution").click(function(e) {
                //e.preventDefault();


        });
```

Only thing I wanna achieve is to make it slide rather than just fade out, fade in (in IE).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the background color is changing via the CSS property of the following div.

```
<div class="module colored home-solutions primary-one-background">
```

The above div is having the class `primary-*-background` updated, where * = 'one' or 'two' or 'three' or 'four' or 'five'.

The CSS is being updated via Javascript in file: http://solutions.mckinsey.com/Index/scripts/main.js

The relevant JS is the following:

```
function updateBackground (pos) {
    $('.home-solutions').removeClass('primary-one-background')
        .removeClass('primary-two-background')
        .removeClass('primary-three-background')
        .removeClass('primary-four-background')
        .removeClass('primary-five-background')
        .addClass($(solution_list[pos]).attr('value'));
....
```

It is removing the `primary-*-background` from all div elements that have class `home-solutions` and then adding the `primary-*-background` class back to those div elements based on the value of `pos`.

The `value` that you pointed out is actually used by the above JS.

```
...
.addClass($(solution_list[pos]).attr('value'));
```

The above is take the value from the div elements you have listed and using that value as the class it is adding to the `home-solutions` div elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, I added an update to my question, could you have alook? Best!

Comment: @Steve no problem.  Are you able to put this in a JS Fiddle so I can see the issue and do some trouble shooting?

Comment: Michael, Thank you for helping me out, I Was able to make it run, but the only thing I wanna achieve is to make it slide rather than just fade out, fade in (in IE). It right now just fade in. Is it possible ? I updated my question.

Comment: @Steve I'm sure that it is possible, but that is out of my league right now unfortunately. Maybe someone else can answer that part for you. I updated the tags on your question.

Comment: Thank you Michael. You were already very helpful nonetheless.